# I want to control the appearance of some select options based on the value of another input field using ngIf angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-templates

Using Angularjs 1.x, I am trying to create a form that has two selects. Based on the option selected in the first select, I want to display more or less options in the second select. Here is the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="container" class="container">
   <form ng-submit="submit();">
      <div align="center">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Size:</td>
               <td>
                  <select  ng-model='size' ng-change="updateSize()" required>
                     <option ng-value='1'>1</option>
                     <option ng-value='2'>2</option>
                     <option ng-value='3'>3</option>
                     <option ng-value='4'>4</option>
                     <option ng-value='5'>5</option>
                  </select>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Number</td>
               <td>
                  <select ng-model='category' required>
                     <div ng-if='{{show1}}'>
                        <option value='1'>1</option>
                     </div>
                     <div ng-if='{{show12}}'>
                        <option value='2'>2</option>
                     </div>
                     <div ng-if='{{show123}}'>
                        <option value='3'>3</option>
                     </div>
                     <div ng-if='{{show1234}}'>
                        <option value='4'>4</option>
                     </div>
                  </select>
               </td>
      </div>
      </tr>
      </table>
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button><br />
      <br /><br />
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

and here is the controller:

```
'use strict';

var ngnControllers = angular.module('ngnControllers');
ngnControllers.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', 
function TestCtrl($scope, $location, $http) {
    $scope.size = 0;
    $scope.category = 0;

    $scope.show1 = false;
    $scope.show12 = false;
    $scope.show123 = false;
    $scope.show1234 = false;

    $scope.updateSize = function() {
    $scope.show1 = parseInt($scope.size, 10) >= 1; 
    $scope.show12 = parseInt($scope.size, 10) >= 2; 
    $scope.show123 = parseInt($scope.size, 10) >= 3; 
    $scope.show1234 = parseInt($scope.size, 10) >= 4; 

    console.log("updateSize called, show1: " + $scope.show1 +
            ", show12: " + $scope.show12 +
            ", show123: " + $scope.show123 +
            ", show1234: " + $scope.show1234);
    };

    $scope.submit = function() {
        console.log("size, category: " + $scope.size + ", " + $scope.category);
        }
}]);
```

The problem I am having is that this is not working. All the options of the second select are displayed all the time. The purpose of the update size function is to turn $scope.show1 etc. into booleans for ngIf. I tried expressions using the value of size, but that didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with:

```
 <option ng-if='show1' value='1'>1</option>
```

Comment: This works, without the interpolation brackets. I would still like to know why, though

Comment: Yes, you are right it will work without the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-if` doesn't use interpolation. You just specify the property

```
<option ng-if="show1" value="1">1</option>
```

see docs (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<select ng-model='category' required>
        <option ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]" data-ng-show="i <= size">
        </option>
</select>
```